# How to run a code only after clicking a button?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a .jsp file, and i want to only do or run the code:

```
<%
ps = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement
("UPDATE words SET english_word=? , chav_word=? , syllabication=? WHERE id=?");
ps.setString(1,request.getParameter("engnew"));
ps.setString(2,request.getParameter("chabnew"));
ps.setString(3,request.getParameter("sylnew"));
ps.setInt(4,id);
ps.executeQuery();
%>
```

After a button is clicked, and here's my html

```
<label>English word:</label><br>
<input type="text" value="<%= eng %>" name="engnew"><br>
<label>Chabacano word:</label><br>
label>Syllabication:</label><br>
<input type="text" value="<%= syl %>" name="sylnew"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
```

How can i only do the codes on the 1st part after the Save button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a servlet and use 
Form method="post" action=actionkey
 and have the action run on button click. Or use JavaScript